# Python Selenium how to select a dropdown option in a google form

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-forms

I'm having trouble to select the different options of this dropdown
in the field SIZE

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdSpGLXjAV_wiI2qgg3B_KYxd4_7NR-DxHGrTySaIkAWIqmBg/viewform

Someone has a good solution?
Im able to click the element with

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[14]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]').click()
```

But I'm not able to select the different options

Comment: Hi Tom, Can you please share a MRE of your problem and what errors you are experiencing? - see here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to click the list to open it, then find and click the span with the right content inside it. Since there is a bit of drawing delay, you'll probably want it to use webdriverwait to ensure the element is ready before interacting.

This works for me:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdSpGLXjAV_wiI2qgg3B_KYxd4_7NR-DxHGrTySaIkAWIqmBg/viewform")


#open the size menu
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='SIZE']/following::div[@class='quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionList'][1]"))).click()

#select the size by it's full text
sizeToSelect = "US 11"
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'exportSelectPopup')]/div/span[text()='"+sizeToSelect+"']"))).click()
```

If you've not already got them you need the following imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Perfect, thankss!! Just another question, how do you find these 2 xpath?

Comment: @zTomX - it's practice mate - use devtools (f12) to inspect what you want, Look for the most stable objects (things such as text() works well) then do ctrl+f to search by xpath (or css or text)  - as you type it it will let you know what has matched. Do that until you get a unique it... After that it's about learning aboout xpaths, their functions and their axes, and if you google it there are lots of resources out there.   :-)   - if this worked for you don't forget to mark it as the right answer

Comment: take a look here to understand how xpath works: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the word SIZE and right-click and click inspect. Now do it again and it will lead you to the HTML regarding that. Keep going down from the root of that very HTML till you find the part of the size you want(as you hover over the code, it will highlight the relevant part in the website). Hope this will help you enough to make the code function.